# Editar archivo owl de servidor y almacenarlo en la misma ubicación mediante sftp

Tags: java, ssh, sftp, owl

Saludos, estoy tratando de hacer una inserción en una archivo .owl (ontología) que se encuentra en un servidor, pero al momento de querer almacenar los cambios me indica que 'El nombre de archivo, el nombre de directorio o la sintaxis de la etiqueta del volumen no son correctos'. Mi método de ingreso es el siguiente:

```
public void insertarDatos(cPersona obj) throws IOException {

    //crear el modelo de la ontologia
    OntModel model = null;
    //asignar el modelo de la ontologia creada
    model = OpenConnectOWL();

    OntClass classEstudiante = model.createClass(NS + "Estudiante");
    Individual Estudiante = model.createIndividual(NS + obj.getNumero(), classEstudiante);

    //Obtenemos las propiedades de la clase
    ...

    //Asignar los valores de las propiedades
    ...

    File file = new File("http://webapp.../RDF-IO.owl");

    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.createNewFile();
    } 

    model.write(new PrintWriter(file));

    try {
        CommandSftp sftp = new CommandSftp();
        String remotePath = "/home/web/ontologias";
        sftp.sendFileToRemote(file, remotePath);
        sftp.disconnect();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

    model.close();
}
```

Tengo que indicar que el método sendFileToRemote() funciona de manera correcta, también he trabajado con la ontología localmente y si se realiza los ingresos, el problema ocurre al querer guardar los cambios en el servidor, pienso que tal vez el inconveniente se esta produciendo en el atributo File, si alguien puede ayudarme con otra solución le estaría muy agradecido.

Comment: Veo cosas importantes, por ejemplo recomiendo que descargues el archivo, lo manipules y después lo vuelvas a subir, para descargarlo nunca lo he hecho como tu, regularmente utilizo lo que recomienda esta url:
http://developando.com/blog/java-leer-guardar-fichero-desde-url

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte, ya lo pude resolver, mediante el uso de ficheros temporales, nada complejo.

Comment: Puedes poner la solución como respuesta para que se quede en SO

Comment: si por favor nos podrias ayudar poniendo tu solución? yo actualmente tengo el mismo lio. Gracias